# How do you command an AppleScripts document to open at login?

Tags: applescript, startup

How do you command an AppleScripts document to open at login?

I am new to AppleScript. I am trying to create a program that opens 2 applications at login. How do I command it to open at startup/ login?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a launch daemon to run on startup

[Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)

[Using launchd with AppleScript to Access a Flash Drive Automatically](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24748)

Save [the plist file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2422542/launchapps.zip) in "~/Library/LaunchAgents", edit the path to point to your script, and restart your computer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.lucy.launchapps</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>/Users/Lucy/Desktop/lucy.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: theEasyWay]

Here is the easiest route for doing this. It should be self explanatory from the picture, but all you have to do is click on the + symbol, locate your application*, and then you're done.

*You can add as many applications as you'd like to.